# Construction of homeomorphism between letters

Tags: general-topology

The problem is this: Construct a homeomorphism from the letter 'Y' to the letter 'T'. Both are consider as a subspaces of $R^2$.

I was thinking that maybe letter Y can be represented as some rotation mapping to get the letter T but didn't get far. Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just lower the two arms to a horizontal position.

Comment: Ok but which mapping would that be so that it is bijective, continuous and that its inverse is continuous?

Comment: Suggestion: Consider the letters as made up of line segments.  Construct the mapping on each segment separately.